# regex to get multiple values in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

my string is

Cuenta de Ahorros | 1231231231 Bs 102,423.88 Cuenta de Ahorros | 1231233123 Usd 102,423.88 Cuenta de Ahorros | 87316633 Usd 10.233 Cuenta de Ahorros | 49189387113313 Usd 12.301

but using **match()** i can't capture all string values

```
const strings = [
  "Cuenta de Ahorros | 1231231231 Bs 102,423.88 Cuenta de Ahorros | 1231233123 Usd 102,423.88 Cuenta de Ahorros | 87316633 Usd 10.233 Cuenta de Ahorros | 49189387113313 Usd 12.301"
]; 

let pattern = /(?<=Bs).*?(?=Cuenta)/;
strings.forEach((s) => {
  console.log(s.match(pattern));
});
```

returns only

> [" 102,423.88 ", 40, "Cuenta de Ahor...] 0 : " 102,423.88 "

i need result like

> Bs 102,423.88
>
> Usd 102,423.88
>
> Usd 10.233
>
> Usd 12.301

Comment: There seems to be many things going on here: If you need `Bs` in the output, and `Usd`, too, you need a group: `(Bs|Usd)`. If you need it in the match, why use lookbehind? Use a consuming pattern. To extract multiple matches, use `g` flag in the regex with `String#match`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you also want to match the dollar variant, you could write the pattern including matching `Bs` and `Usd` as:

```
\b(?:Bs|Usd)\s+(?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?|\d{4,})(?=\s+Cuenta\b|$)
```

**Explanation**

- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial word match
- `(?:Bs|Usd)`
- `\s+` Match 1= whitespace chars
- `(?:` Non capture

  - `\d{1,3}` Match 1-3 digits
  - `(?:,\d{3})*` Optionally repeat `,` and 3 digits
  - `(?:\.\d+)?` Optionally match `.` and 1 + digits
  - `|` Or
  - `\d{4,}` Match 4 or more digits
- `)` Close non capture group
- `(?=\s+Cuenta\b|$)` Assert either 1+ whitespace chars and Cuenta to the right or assert the end of the string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iyCA8h/1)

```js
const pattern = /\b(?:Bs|Usd)\s+(?:\d+(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?|\d{4,})(?=\s+Cuenta\b|$)/g;
const strings = [
  "Cuenta de Ahorros | 1231231231 Bs 102,423.88 Cuenta de Ahorros | 1231233123 Usd 102,423.88 Cuenta de Ahorros | 87316633 Usd 10.233 Cuenta de Ahorros | 49189387113313 Usd 12.301"
];

strings.forEach((s) => {
  console.log(s.match(pattern));
});
```

Or using matchAll with a capture group:

```js
const pattern = /(\b(?:Bs|Usd)\s+(?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?|\d{4,}))(?:\s+Cuenta\b|$)/g;
const strings = [
  "Cuenta de Ahorros | 1231231231 Bs 102,423.88 Cuenta de Ahorros | 1231233123 Usd 102,423.88 Cuenta de Ahorros | 87316633 Usd 10.233 Cuenta de Ahorros | 49189387113313 Usd 12.301"
];

strings.forEach((s) => {
  console.log(Array.from(s.matchAll(pattern), m => m[1]));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```js
const strings = [
  "Cuenta de Ahorros | 1231231231 Bs 102,423.88 Cuenta de Ahorros | 1231233123 Usd 102,423.88 Cuenta de Ahorros | 87316633 Usd 10.233 Cuenta de Ahorros | 49189387113313 Usd 12.301"
]; 

let pattern = /\b(?:Bs|Usd)\b.*?(?=\s*Cuenta\b|$)/gi;
strings.forEach((s) => {
  console.log(s.match(pattern));
});
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iHXLU7/1).

*Pattern details*:

- `\b(?:Bs|Usd)\b` - a whole word `Bs` or `Usd`
- `.*?` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `(?=\s*Cuenta\b|$)` - a positive lookahead that requires (immediately to the right of the current location) either zero or more whitespaces and then a whole word `Cuenta` (`\s*Cuenta\b|$`), or end of string (`$`).

I added `g` flag and used `String#match` to extract all matches from a string, and `i` flag makes the search case-insensitive.